# Problems validating iOS App build

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I'm working with a developer to create an iOS App for a client. I created my certificates, provisioning profiles, etc, and then sent it to the developer to build the App. They have then sent me back the build as an .xarchive file, which I have loaded up into Xcode.

On the Archives tab, I then go to validate it, but the developer certificate I created in iTunes connect is invalid.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gCYIi.png]

I created both my developer and distribution signature inside the same iTunes Connect account, and they're both loaded up in Keychain along with my WWDR certificate.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HxHi8.png]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you downloaded and dragged your provisioning files to XCode as well.

Answer (score 0):

When producing a build using a Distribution Certificate you need to make sure that you have a properly generated Distribution Certificate in the iOS Provisioning Portal. Select the Certificates -> Distribution tab and make sure you have a distribution certificate listed. If there is one and you do not have the original private key on your machine, you will need to obtain the private/public key pair from the original machine, or revoke and recreate the certificate.

[image]

Also, make sure you have created a Distribution provisioning profile and that it is being used in conjunction with this Distribution Certificate.

Also, check to be sure you have a distribution provisioning profile for your app for app store.

[image]

Other problems include the App ID differing from the Bundle Identifier and it has trouble associating it with the provisioning profile. Most commonly when the Bundle Identifier is derived from the ProductName and the case of the characters doesn't match the case of the characters in the App ID on the provisioning portal.

You can get around this by typing in the bundle identifier into the AppName-info.plist file.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my certificates in Keychain - http://i.imgur.com/HxHi8.png

As far as I can tell, I have a distribution certificate!

Comment: Have you generated a distribution provisioning profile in the distribution section of the provisioning profiles tab? If so you may need to re-download the profile or click the refresh button in the organizer window of Xcode to refresh your account provisioning profiles. After this do a clean and try archiving a new version. You can double check your code signing settings in your targets build settings view in xcode. Check to see if it is showing up in there.

Comment: If my answer helped you please check the checkmark. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out! I had the right certificates, but had only created a development provisioning profile. I created this in iTunes Connect and then it worked perfectly. Hope this helps someone else who has a similar problem.

Easiest way to ensure you have everything I needed is to remember that you need separate certificates and provisioning profiles for development and distribution. They can all be created in iTunes Connect, and you just need to download them and run the file to ensure Xcode finds them.